# Rewriting Get method url to friendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using get method and getting this url where =diamond and =Shining value will be changed based
on user selection and everything will be same but this url looks messy I want to convert it into friendly url.

Current Url: `http://localhost/key/inside/yes.html?ser=diamond&type=Shining&submit=Send`

Frinedly Url: `http://localhost/key/inside/yes/ser/diamond/type/Shining/`

I want to know how can i do it using .htaccess and it's ok to do with .htaccess or php is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `/key/inside/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /key/inside/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.html?$2=$3&$4=$5&submit=Send [L,QSA]
```